# Link inside iframe wont work

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

This drives me totally crazy now. A link (http://ns.nl) on the page inside the iframe I made wont work (http://newsoundsofeurope.com/videos/playlisttest). Chrome doesn't do anything after the mouse click. Firefox just opens a blank page inside the iframe. Anyone can help?

Page with iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="playlist_iframe.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Page inside iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://ns.nl" target="_self"><img src="026.png"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `target="_self` and will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open that link with a new page, you need to set the target="_blank"

```
<a href="http://ns.nl" target="_blank"><img src="026.png"/></a>
```

Also need to set the 'allow-popups' permission in the iframe

```
<iframe src="playlist_iframe.php" sandbox="allow-popups"></iframe>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp